# XML - Select xmlNode depending on innertext

Tags: c#, xml, document

I have a 'xmlDocument'-Object, 
which contains this structure:

```
<Projects>
  <Project>
    <Name>Value1</Name>
  </Project>
  <Project>
    <Name>Value2</Name>
  </Project>
</Projects>
```

I need to change these values on runtime via c#.
My thought was

- create new 'xmlnode'-Object
- Change its innertext
- save the document

But I don't know how to select the xml-node depending on its innertext.
I researched a bit, and tried that:

```
XmlNode nameNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Projects\\Project\\Name[text()='" + projectName + "']");
```

which causes 'XPathException'.

How do you write the path on the right way?

Comment: So you want select a <Name> tag that has a specified inner text?

Comment: exactly. For example, I want to select and change the innertext of the name-tag, where name=="Value1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using LINQ to XML instead of XPath:

```
XDocument doc = ...; // However you load the XML
XElement element = doc.Root
                      .Elements("Project")
                      .Elements("Name")
                      .Where(x => x.Value == projectName)
                      .SingleOrDefault();
// Check whether or not element is null (if so, you haven't found it)
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me by changing it to "..Elements("Name")..."

Comment: @Marcel: Yes, sorry, that was a change I made when I was editing thinking you wanted the `Project` element.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this was asked a long time ago and an alternative solution was found, but I had similar issue and I managed to solve it using xpath by use of a XmlNodeList with the following

```cs
XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;

XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='Projects'//*[local-name()='Project'//*[local-name()='Name'][text()='" + projectName + "']");
```

You can then loop through the XmlNodeList

```cs
foreach (XmlNode xn in nodes)....
```

posting in case anyone else would like to use this method